# how to leave program with f12 after write

Tags: abap

Once I leave the selection screen in ABAP e.g. by write: How to rewrite cancel button behavior? In my shortened code below, each time I click execute and then cancel, I'm back at the selection screen :( Instead of this behavior I want to leave the program entirely when clicking in write output the red button.

```
    PARAMETERS p_output AS CHECKBOX DEFAULT ' '.

    SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN 101 AS SUBSCREEN.
    SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK such WITH FRAME TITLE text-001.
    "...
    SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK such.
    SELECTION-SCREEN END OF SCREEN 101.

    SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN 102 AS SUBSCREEN.
    SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK such2 WITH FRAME TITLE text-002.
    "...
    SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK such2.
    SELECTION-SCREEN END OF SCREEN 102.


    SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF TABBED BLOCK searchtab FOR 20 LINES.
    SELECTION-SCREEN TAB (15) expert USER-COMMAND ucomm1
    DEFAULT SCREEN 101.
    SELECTION-SCREEN TAB (17) common USER-COMMAND ucomm2
    DEFAULT SCREEN 102.
    SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK searchtab.

    INITIALIZATION.
      expert = text-001.
      common = text-002.
      searchtab-prog = sy-repid.
      searchtab-dynnr = 101.
      searchtab-activetab = 'EXPERT_SEARCH'.

      "...
       AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON EXIT-COMMAND.

      CASE sy-dynnr.
        WHEN 1000."main screen number
          CASE sy-ucomm.
            WHEN 'ECAN'.
               LEAVE PROGRAM.
            WHEN 'DBAC' OR 'ENDE'. "execute go back
               LEAVE TO SCREEN 1000." SELECTION-SCREEN 1000.
            WHEN 'UCOMM1'.
               searchtab-dynnr = 101."subscreen number 1
               searchtab-activetab = 'EXPERT'.
            WHEN 'UCOMM2'.
              searchtab-dynnr = 102."subscreen number 2
              searchtab-activetab = 'COMMON'.
            ENDCASE.
        WHEN Others.
            CASE sy-ucomm.
               WHEN 'ECAN'.
              LEAVE PROGRAM.
             WHEN 'DBAC' OR 'ENDE'. "execute go back
                LEAVE TO SCREEN 1000." SELECTION-SCREEN 1000.
              ENDCASE.
        ENDCASE.

        START-OF-SELECTION.
        PERFORM say_hello.

     FORM say_hello .
        WRITE: 'from the write output screen I want to navigate by Cancel button or key f12', 
       'not back to selection screen but leave the program entirely.'.
      ENDFORM.                    " SAY_HELLO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what works, it's not pretty.

1. Copy GUI status INLI from program SAPMSSY0 to your own program
2. Change the OK code for the cancel button. To work with your example code, change it to ECAN. Also change the one in the Edit menu to be complete
3. As the first command in your `START-OF-SELECTION` use
   `SET PF-STATUS 'INLI'.` This is assuming you named it the same
4. Change the `AT SELECTION-SCREEN` to `AT USER-COMMAND`
5. Activate, test and be amazed

This works because it removes the standard behavior for lists and replaces it with your own, only for the cancel button mind you. Without changing the OK code for cancel the standard SAP code will take over and you have no control over the behavior.

Comment: can you please explain where to change the Ok-code of the button? Is ist in the menu painter somewhere?

Comment: sorry, I just found out how to do that. cool. just needed to type INLI in status field in SE41.